# crypt library and block size

Tags: c, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am using a **128-bit AES** symmetric-key encryption function that was given to me. I keep getting this seg fault while decrypting:

> :error:0606506D:lib(6):func(101):reason(109):evp_enc.c:518:

At first when testing encrypting/decrypting together, I would get this error because my buffer to store the encryption and decryption wasn't large enough. Please help me troubleshoot:

1. When storing the key (using fgets), for some reason the char array to store it required size 34 instead of 33 (i dont think this is the problem but who knows)
2. the formatting i'm using to decrypt is wrong (I am pretty sure it requires raw binary, ive tried hex as well)
3. something else is messing with the block size.

What else could this be from?

Comment: OpenSSL? Your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

128-bit aes symmetric-key length must have to be 16 byte.

also 256-bit aes symmetric-key length must have to be 32 byte.